# Laravel reject function on nested collection

Tags: laravel, laravel-collection

I am trying to iterate my collection, which has nested collections, with the collection `reject()` function and return the original collection with the updated nested data.

So this is my quiz collection

```
{
 "id": 1,
 "title": "quiz 1",
 "questions": [
     {
         "id": 1,
         "quiz_id": 1,
         "question": "q1 - q1",
         "answers": [
             {
                 "id": 1,
                 "question_id": 1,
                 "answer": "answer to question 1"
             },
             {
                 "id": 2,
                 "question_id": 1,
                 "answer": "answer to question 1"
             }
         ]
     },
     {
         "id": 2,
         "quiz_id": 1,
         "question": "q1 - q2",
         "answers": [
             {
                 "id": 3,
                 "question_id": 2,
                 "answer": "answer to question 1"
             }
         ]
     }
 ]
}
```

Now I want to iterate through the questions and reject those that were already answered and exist in the result collection. I do so by using the `reject()` function

```
$quizResults = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "user_id": 1,
        "quiz_id": 1,
        "question_id": 1,
        "answer_id": 1,
        "correct": 1,
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null
    }
];

$filtered = $quiz->questions->reject(function ($value, $key) use ($quizResult) {
   return $quizResult->contains('question_id', $value->id);
});
```

I want to return the quiz collection with the updated questions (without the rejected questions), but I can't seem to figure out the correct way to accomplish this. (if i return just the $filtered variable i get the correct filtered results, however if i try putting it back in to the $quiz var it won't apply the rejected filter). If I just do

```
return $quiz
```

I will get the same original collection with all the questions as if I never ran the `reject()` function.

How do I make the `$quiz->questions = $filtered;` ?

Comment: can you give us an example of `$quizResult`? like your `$quiz`

Comment: @AndySong i added it to the edit, thx.

Answer (score 0):

This is the min steps to reproduce your problem,

```php
    $quizResult = [
        0 => [
          'id' => 1,
          'user_id' => 1,
          'quiz_id' => 1,
          'question_id' => 1,
          'answer_id' => 1,
          'correct' => 1,
          'created_at' => null,
          'updated_at' => null,
        ],
    ];

    $quiz = [
        'id' => 1,
        'title' => 'quiz 1',
        'questions' => [
          0 => [
            'id' => 1,
            'quiz_id' => 1,
            'question' => 'q1 - q1',
            'answers' => [
              0 => [
                'id' => 1,
                'question_id' => 1,
                'answer' => 'answer to question 1',
              ],
              1 => [
                'id' => 2,
                'question_id' => 1,
                'answer' => 'answer to question 1',
              ],
            ],
          ],
          1 => [
            'id' => 2,
            'quiz_id' => 1,
            'question' => 'q1 - q2',
            'answers' => [
              0 => [
                'id' => 3,
                'question_id' => 2,
                'answer' => 'answer to question 1',
              ],
            ],
          ],
        ],
    ];

    $filtered = collect($quiz['questions'])->reject(function ($value) use ($quizResult) {
        return collect($quizResult)->contains('question_id', $value['id']);
    });
    $quiz['questions'] = $filtered;

    return $quiz;
```

And this the result,

```
{
"id": 1,
"title": "quiz 1",
"questions": {
"1": {
"id": 2,
"quiz_id": 1,
"question": "q1 - q2",
"answers": [
  {
         "id": 3,
         "question_id": 2,
         "answer": "answer to question 1"
  }
 ]
}
}
}
```

I do not understand why you said it's returning original one.

Comment: yes thats what i am trying to achieve, the issue is return $quiz will just return both questions without applying the rejected filtered changes

Comment: @Mika can you give us an example of `$quizResult`? like your `$quiz`

Comment: $quizResults = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "user_id": 1,
        "quiz_id": 1,
        "question_id": 1,
        "answer_id": 1,
        "correct": 1,
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null
    }
];

Comment: @Mika, have you run the code I provided? it will give what you want, will not give you both.

Comment: yes i ran your code, still the same, if i return just $filtered i get one answer, but if i return $quiz even after doing your code i get both answers (in other words it goes back to its original)

Comment: @Mika, wait, you want to filter questions right? there is nothing to do with answers. am I right?

Comment: the answers belong to the questions so when the questions gets rejected so should the answer. Which happens when returning just the $filtered but for some odd reason not when I return $quiz even after I do $quiz->questions = $filtered. Your result in your answer is perfect, but I don't understand why that won't come out for me I'm doing exactly the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Pass it by reference

```php
$filtered = $quiz->questions->reject(function ($value, $key) use (&$quizResult) {
   return $quizResult->contains('question_id', $value->id);
});
```

Comment: its still returning the same original $quiz and not applying the reject function

Answer (score 0):

I had to unset the $quiz['questions'] first so it was like this

```
unset($quiz['questions']);
$quiz['questions'] = $filtered->flatten();
return $quiz;
```

and the result was as intended:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "quiz 1",
    "questions": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "quiz_id": 1,
            "question": "q1 - q2",
            "answers": [
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "question_id": 2,
                    "answer": "answer to question 1"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```